# Javascript to make input field in edit mode(insert mode)

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to make a input field editable in javascript. I mean onFocus putting it in insert mode so that values can be overwritten. Any suggestions ???

Comment: Isn't an input field already editable? You're talking about <input type="text"> right?

Comment: @mplacona: he means mimicking the insert button on the keyboard to overwrite the following character.

Comment: I read it as implementing edit-in-place, but it could also read as saving a plain, old input into a database. More clarification is needed.

Comment: @ajm: You're right, it can read either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some googling, [this seems](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/150118-how-can-i-change-insert-typeover-mode-text-box) to be related. It might be working trying the play with the following code a bit, but it might only work in specific browsers on specific operating systems, but it's worth a shot anyway.

```
document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, true);
document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, false);
```

As per your request, I would say the implementation would work something like this:

```
<input type="text" 
    onFocus="document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, true);"
    onBlur="document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, false);">
```

Comment: I would +1 here if this were more cross browser compatible.  As it happens, only Internet Explorer supports it.  In fact, it appears only IE supports the insert key for input overwriting.

Comment: I tried using this but no success... can you provide a shor example, how to implement it. I am using onKeypress event. Thanks

Comment: 2020 Update: This works for IE, but not Firefox, Chromium, or Edge Legacy. The Insert Key does work in ContentEditable areas in Chromium, but not Firefox. https://webdbg.com/test/edit/

Answer (score 13):

This should work in modern browsers (also on mobile):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input'); // or a textarea
input.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  const s = this.selectionStart;
  this.value = this.value.slice(0, s) + this.value.slice(s + 1);
  this.selectionEnd = s;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sample" />
```

*Note: This is a basic form of insert functionality so some default functionality like CTRL+Z may break.*

Comment: With this solution, you have lost ctrl-z capability unfortunately.

Comment: @DiegoPamio Unfortunately it is. I've tried to make my own CTRL+Z implementation but it failed in many cases.

Comment: This also works:
`this.setSelectionRange(this.selectionStart, this.selectionStart + 1);`

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N56JJ/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: May be totally off-topic, depending on the meaning behind the question.

If you can use jQuery, [Jeditable is a nice plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to do just that.

If you must roll your own code, take a look at how that plugin works and use it as a starting point.

Basically, the steps are:

1. onFocus/onClick - swap your field with an input.
2. When the user is "done" (hit Enter, click a button), push the result back to the server via Ajax.
3. When your request completes, update the interface with the new value, hiding the input.

Comment: +1, I was just about to suggest this. I prefer to think of this plugin as being called 'Jedi Table'.

Comment: Wow. I'm going with Jedi Table from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mimic Insert mode by rewriting the input value on keyup :

```
var input = $('input'); // your input element

Event.observe(input, 'keydown', function(e) { // event handler
   input._lastvalue = input.value;
});

Event.observe(input, 'keyup', function(e) { // event handler
    if(input.value == input._lastvalue) return;
    if(input.value.length <= input._lastvalue.length) return;
    var caretPos = doGetCaretPosition(input);
    input.value = input.value.slice(0,caretPos) + input.value.slice(caretPos+1);
    doSetCaretPosition(input, caretPos);
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z6khW/

Comment: Thanks for your effort...I tried th eexample but actually it tries to select remaining all characters and deletes 'em.

Comment: Oops didn't test on IE, only FF.