# Overtype mode with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I make my input field act as if the keyboard is in overtype mode?

I tried to trigger the keypress event with the delete button in keycode when the user enter a value but nothing happen.

Comment: You could manually grab the data in the input field, check where the new letter was added and remove the letter after it?

Comment: The problem is know where the letter as been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<input onkeydown="this.oldSize = this.value.length;" 
  onkeypress="var n = this; setTimeout(function() {
      if(n.value.length > n.oldSize) {
        var s = n.selectionStart;
        n.value = n.value.substr(0, s) + n.value.substr(s + 1);
        n.selectionStart = n.selectionEnd = s;
      }
    },10);">
```

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution based on the selectionStart attribute.

Comment: Sorry i didn't have the time to post the awser yesterday.
For the people who could be interested i found this web site who help me to reply to my own question: http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php#supByObj

Comment: And here is the code who's replying to my question with jQuery :
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$('input').keypress(function(){
    pos = this.selectionStart;
    this.selectionStart = pos;
    this.selectionEnd = pos + 1;
}

Comment: When the user press a key, i select the caractere just after the cursor. As a consequence, the caractere selected is replace by the caractere entered by the user.

Comment: An easier solution but only for IE here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561110/javascript-to-make-input-field-in-edit-modeinsert-mode

Answer (score 0):

well, i have no idea what you wanna do.maybe this will help you.

Keymaster is a simple (100 LoC or so) micro-library for defining and dispatching keyboard shortcuts. It has no dependencies.

https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster#readme