# Can I use or turn on the 'insert' caret in modern browsers using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I'd prefer the old flashing box caret (instead of the standard flashing line) that erases the character it is currently situated over and replaces it with whatever the user just typed.

In my case, I would like it for

```
<input type='text' />
```

but even just turning it on anywhere would be great.

I recall it wasn't so easy to turn on in native windows programming, so I'm not expecting much here.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You could turn on the Insert mode using the insert key probably...

Comment: is this for an input, textarea, or contenteditable div?

Comment: I want <input type='text'/> but see if you can turn it on anywhere else, it's a challenge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox, Safari, and Chrome do not support an insert, over over-write, mode.  In IE (only) you can query if it is turned on by the OS via `document.queryCommandValue("OverWrite")` but there is not a way to set it.

However, it can be [mimicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503798/overtype-mode-with-jquery).

Comment: yeah, I see gmail is simulating the effect by 'selecting' single characters. I don't like it though, its not always obvious you're in 'insert' mode because the selected characters don't flash.